# Horizontal align the TikZ picture in itemize label position

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

I am going to use custom itemize label created by `TikZ`, however can not align it as other labels:

[image]

I tried `shift` but it is no work. I know that maybe I should change the itemize settings, however it will be move the other labels too.

Which is the optimal method to align custom mark horizontally same as bullets?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}           
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$,leftmargin=0mm,
itemindent=7mm,labelsep=2mm,topsep=1mm,itemsep=-1mm,parsep=1mm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\clabel}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline=(alrt.base)]
    \draw[thick,red,fill=yellow,rounded corners](0,0) --(0.5,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \node(alrt) at (0.5,0.4) {\textbf{!}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item OK Here
  \item[\clabel] Not OK\dots It must be a little bit right
  \item OK again
\end{itemize}   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the custom itemize labels grow to the left. You can fix it by adding `overlay` and a `xshift`:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}           
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$,leftmargin=0mm,
itemindent=7mm,labelsep=2mm,topsep=1mm,itemsep=-1mm,parsep=1mm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\clabel}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline=(alrt.base), overlay, xshift=-3ex]
    \draw[thick,red,fill=yellow,rounded corners](0,0) --(0.5,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \node(alrt) at (0.5,0.4) {\textbf{!}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item OK Here
  \item[\clabel] Not OK\dots It must be a little bit right
  \item OK again
\end{itemize}   

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]